# Get Cell Value From Another Sheet USING ADDRESS and MATCH

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have here a condition/function. I'm not really experienced in Google Sheets.

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(B32,Diana!B:B,0),1)
```

Now, Diana is another worksheet. The result from the function above is `$A$2`. I  want to get the result or the cell value of `Diana!A2`. How should I make that happen??

Comment: `=INDEX(Diana!A:A,MATCH(B32,Diana!B:B,0))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDIRECT("Diana!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B32, Diana!B:B, 0), 1))
```

Comment: Saw this one from some support yesterday and it worked. Thank you, anyway!